# genre syntax didn't return classification data

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

AS title my data index is: "ntopng-2018.01.02"

this is my REST API:

```
GET ntopng-2018.01.02/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                    "term": {
                        "IPV4_SRC_ADDR": "120.127.160.91"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "IPV4_DST_ADDR": "120.127.160.91"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "must": [{
                "range": {
                    "LAST_SWITCHED": {
                        "gte": 1514800209
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "genres": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "L7_PROTO_NAME.keyword"
            }

            ,
            "aggs": {
                "in_bytes": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "IN_BYTES"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the response:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 6,
    "successful": 6,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 282,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "genres": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": []
    }
  }
}
```

It didn't classify `L7_PROTO_NAME`, but if I change to another index "logstash-2018.01.02" (the same data type fields), it would return classified data.

This is my data, https://gist.github.com/Howard-Chang/808ed0f4c64c528051f284cee3ac0634.

Comment: The `_type` in your `logstash-2018.01.02` index looks different than the one in your `ntopng-2018.01.02` index, i.e. `ntopng-*` resp. `ntopng`. Can you provide the mapping for both of your indices please?

Comment: I put in the url: https://gist.github.com/Howard-Chang/808ed0f4c64c528051f284cee3ac0634

Comment: Can you pretty print the mappings? i.e. add `?pretty` to the URL

Comment: ok, I update it.

Comment: Ok, but the `IPV4_SRC_ADDR` and `IPV4_DEST_ADDR` in your sample document don't match `120.127.160.91`

Comment: sorry, I just paste a casual sample. I don't know why it didn't return the aggregation genre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. I found that's old ES version problem.
I can't use the genre syntax to query and return correct result if the index isn't "logstash-*".
but after I update to the newest 6.1.1 version, and it can run now!